# Copy everything except files on the list

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to copy all files recursively from `a:\` to `b:\`, **except** those whose metadata is present in `a:\list.txt`. The `list.txt` pattern is LastWriteTimeYYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,size,.fileextension, for example:

```
2001-01-31 23:59:59,12345,.doc
2001-01-31 23:59:59,12345,.txt
2001-01-31 23:59:00,456,.csv
```

...so any and all files, anywhere in the `a:\` dir tree, matching these metadata should **not** be copied.

I seem to be having trouble with the `Where-Object` in order to exclude the items on the `list.txt`, but copy everything  else:

```
$Source = "C:\a"
$Target = "C:\b"

$List = Import-Csv list.txt -Header LastWriteTime,Size,Name

$Hash = @{}
ForEach ($Row in $List){
    $Key = ("{0},{1},.{2}" -F $Row.LastWriteTime,$Row.Size,$Row.Name.Split('.')[-1].ToLower())
    IF (!($Hash[$Key])) {$Hash.Add($Key,$Row.Name)}
}
$Hash | Format-Table -Auto

Get-Childitem -Path $Source -Recurse -File | Where-Object {$Hash -eq $Hash[$Key]}| ForEach-Object {$Key = ("{0},{1},{2}" -F ($_.LastWriteTime).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),$_.Length,$_.Extension.ToLower())
    #$Key
    If ($Hash[$Key]){
        $Destination = $_.FullName -Replace "^$([RegEx]::Escape($Source))","$Target"
        If (!(Test-Path (Split-Path $Destination))){MD (Split-Path $Destination)|Out-Null}
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
    }
}
```

Comment: > `-Exclude` Omits the specified items. The value of this parameter qualifies the -Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as "*.txt". - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1 You want to test dates and file sizes and names? Exclude isn't complex enough to do that, you'll have to do it yourself with a `Where-Object {}` filter between `Get-ChildItem` and `ForEach-Object`

Comment: The strategy: hash the date,size,.ext in the list.txt, then hash date,size,.ext for all files in `a:`. Then, copy all files from `a:` to `b:` except those whose hash is present on the list.txt.

Comment: `-Recurse -File Where-Object {` -> `-Recurse -File | Where-Object {`

Comment: Thank you.  Would not `Compare-Object` be better than `Where-object`? Also, the script works for the "reverse" (i.e., it would copy files specified in list.txt), so I am wondering if there is a easy way to instead skip list.txt files (defined by metadata) and copy everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a simplification of your code :

```
$Source = "C:\a\"
$Target = "C:\b\"

New-Item -ItemType Directory $Target -Force | Out-Null

$List = Import-Csv list.txt -Header LastWriteTime,Length,Extension

Get-Childitem $Source -Recurse -File | %{
$File=$_

$exist=$List | where {$_.LastWriteTime -eq $File.LastWriteTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') -and $_.Length -eq $File.Length -and $_.Extension -eq $File.Extension} | select -first 1 
if ($exist -ne $null) {continue}

New-Item -ItemType Directory $File.DirectoryName.Replace($Source, $Target) -Force | Out-Null
Copy-Item $File.FullName $File.FullName.Replace($Source, $Target) -Force 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried running it several times. It does not copy anything from `a:` (`a:` has 21 files and 1 subdir) to `b:`, even though the `list.txt` has only  1 line: `2015-01-25 14:26:24,1696,jpg` corresponding with 1 file. So I would expect that everything gets copied except this file. No error messages in PS.

Comment: There is a typo in the code `yyy` needs to be `yyyy` (line 11). But this does not fix the problem.

Comment: Have you remove "what-if" ?

Comment: Because your extension into list dont hâve dot like given into your first example

Comment: Not sure what you mean _"Have you remove "what-if""_ ? I do not see `what-if` in your code. It does not work with or without the dot `.`  (e.g., `2015-01-25 14:26:24,1696,jpg` or ...`,.jpg`), and also, if it's not a 100% match between a file's metadata and any line in the `list.txt`, then it should copy from `a:` to `b:`. So by "default" it needs to copy everything, and skip any and all files whose metadata is on the list.

Comment: about "So by "default" it needs to copy everything, and skip any and all files whose metadata is on the list. ", modify '-eq $null' to '-ne $null', i have modified my code for this

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work on initial testing, except it does not copy files in subdir of `a:` that are not on the list.txt.